# `<module:Generators>': undefined method `mattr_accessor' for Rails::Generators:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a fresh installation of Ruby on my Manjaro Arch Linux.

```
[parin@excalibur Desktop]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

I installed rails using `gem install rails`
Now on trying to generate a new project, I get the following error:

```
[parin@excalibur Desktop]$ rails new test
/home/parin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/generators.rb:24:in `<module:Generators>': undefined method `mattr_accessor' for Rails::Generators:Module (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  attr_accessor
    from /home/parin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/generators.rb:15:in `<module:Rails>'
    from /home/parin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/generators.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/parin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/parin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/parin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/parin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /home/parin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I am a noob in Ruby and Rails both so would appreciate some help here.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: what is your version of rubygems? run `gem -v`

Comment: It looks like the gems in use were installed for an older version of Ruby (2.3.0) than you are currently using (Ruby 2.3.1p112)

Comment: I don't believe that's necessarily true. Ruby doesn't change the base directory between minor versions. Here's an example path from my 2.3.1 installation: `/Users/jbodah/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0`

Comment: Have you already run `bundle install`? If so, are you able to post your `Gemfile.lock`? It looks like ActiveSupport isn't being included into the runtime